# What command is gimp using to print?

Tags: command-line, printing, gimp, lp, lpr

All programs/commands I attempt to print certain PDFs with (`lpr`, `lp`, Okular, Evince, Xpdf) print solid black pages.  The one exception is Gimp, which allows me to import PDFs one page at a time and properly print.

Obviously, this isn't a practical solution for multiple PDFs, so I would like to see exactly what command Gimp is using to print so I can try reproducing it from the command line.

I tried running it with the `--verbose` flag and printing, but there doesn't seem to be any output showing the `lp` or `lpr` command Gimp is using.  How can I catch this print command?

---

**Please Note**: I'm not looking for help with the blank page printing problem.  There are a ton of posts on that on the internet and it just seems to be black magic how one works for some people but not others.  Please refrain from answering/commenting about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `pdfinfo` on the PDF generated by GIMP's print function, as well as checking the PDF file generated by GIMPs's post script function suggests that the program doing the print is Cairo.

Here is the line in the Postscript file:

```
Creator: cairo 1.14.8 (http://cairographics.org)
```

Comment: @GAD3R Is that an answer to the question or a comment on this answer?